# Make `==` a generic funciton in R

Tags: r, generics, r-s4, equality-operator

I would like to make `==` a generic function.

When I run: `setGeneric("==")`, the definition does not appear to change:

```
> `==`
function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("==")
> setGeneric("==")
[1] "=="
> `==`
function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("==")
```

And when I call `` setgeneric("`==`") ``, I get the following error:

```
> setGeneric("`==`")
Error in setGeneric("`==`") : 
  must supply a function skeleton for ‘`==`’, explicitly or via an existing function
```

I can define the `==` function with:

```
`==` <- function(x,y) 42;
```

And then I can use `setGeneric` on it. But then I'd have to put the body of the original `==` there, which seems clunky.

So is there any way to make `==` be generic in S4?

Comment: The primitive functions should do [method dispatching in the C code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e0104656589073490591cefb12997178362feb7a/src/main/relop.c#L51). Do you have an example of something that isn't working the way you expect? Can you make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Oh, wow, I was basing that off of the output I got when evaluating ==. I just called == and it did what I want. Here was my code: https://gist.github.com/LeifAndersen/993fa5e320827f8c3654

Comment: So then this matter is settled? No need to call `setGeneric("==")`, right?

Comment: (Should one of us put this in the answer field?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963291/writing-an-s4-generic-method-with-two-arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MrFlick's response:

It turns out that `==` is already generic (implement in C). So you don't need to call `setGeneric`.

Rather, you can just use `setMethod`.

```
setMethod("==",
          c(e1="Class1",e2="Class2"),
          funciton(e1,e2) { .... })
```